# How to create tables in codefirst approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am working on Login page creating in C# using Code First approach , in this I am getting  lot of errors while trying to execute the code. I am a fresher and new to this .

Can you please review my code and help me what I missed in this ?

Rule are not creating and getting the multiple errors. Your help would help me to understand what went wrong in this.

**My Class "Class1.cs"**

```
public class Login
    {
        [Required]
        public string username { get; set; }
       [Required]
        public string password{ get; set; }

    }
}
public class LoginContext : DbContext
{
    public LoginContext() : base("LoginDBConnectionString")
    {

        Database.SetInitializer<LoginContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<LoginContext>());
    }


    public DbSet<username> username { get; set; }
    public DbSet<password> password { get; set; }

}
```

**Context.cs**

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Jquery1.Models;

namespace Jquery1.Models
{
    public class Logincontext: DbContext
    {
        public Logincontext () : base ("LoginDBConnectionString")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Login> Logins{ get; set; }

    }
  }

class program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (var ctx = new Logincontext())
        {
            ctx.Database.Create();
        }`enter code here`
    }
}
```

Comment: You are going to have to provide a lot more information. Where is your code? What errors? Where are they thrown?

Comment: @David Thnx , my code attached

Comment: provide the error that you got here, otherwise it will be very hard for people to help you, also why is LoginContext different in both examples? Where are the username and password classes? DbSet represents a table in the DB, I think you are confusing them with columns

Answer (score 1):

Hi Let me explain this using `fluent api` bear with me a little please,

Create Your `DbContext` First:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("name=MyConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, YourApplication.Migrations.Configuration>("MyConnection")); 
    }
    public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //here you can MAP Your Models/Entities, but i am going to show you something more interesting. so keep up. 
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UsersMap());
    }
}
```

Create a Migration Folder in your app root And make `Configuration` class there(Why?! so that everytime you made a change migration of EF will update the Tables for you):

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourApplication.Infrastructure.Data.MyDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        //this feature on true can result in unwanted/unexpected dataloss
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        ContextKey = "YourApplication.Infrastructure.Data.MyDbContext";
    }

    protected override void Seed(YourApplication.Infrastructure.Data.MyDbContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
}
```

Now Go on And Create Your `POCO` Classes. I try to write my codes very clean. That's why when for example i made a `Model` like below, i create an `EntityBase` for every `Id`:

```
public class EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And Implement it to my `Model` :

```
public class User: EntityBase
{
    public string Example1{ get; set; }
    public string Example2{ get; set; }
    public string Example3{ get; set; }
}
```

And For Mapping I Create another Class like below and use `Fluent Api`:

```
public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        //declaring the table name
        ToTable("TblUser");
        //declaring primary key of the table
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        //declaring a property from poco class is required
        Property(x => x.Example1)
            .IsRequired();
        //etc

    }
}
```

be aware if you are using fluent api, you Shouldn't use Data Annotations. Happy Coding.

Comment: Also, don't forget to disable automatic migrations in production environments. You current configuration can result in unwanted/unexpected dataloss.

Answer (score 0):

Entity frame-work uses a concept of standards-or-else. If you want your items fairly standard, you don' have to provide a lot of information. If you want your tables to have different names, or your columns to be different than standard you'll have to provide extra information using either Attributes (the method you use) or fluent API.

Every class that should become a table should have an Primary key. The default is to give your class a property Id, or to give the property the name of your class followed by Id:

```
public class Login
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string UserName {get; set;}
    public string Password {get; set;}
}
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Login> Logins {get; set;}
}
```

This should be enough to give you a table with the default name, which is the plural of your class name Logins. Each record in the table has three columns:

- Id: the primary key
- UserName: a string, which in this case may be null
- PassWord: a string which may be null.

Your Requires attribute will ensure that your UserName and Property are not null, but they won't prevent them being empty. I'm not sure that's enough for you.

Instead of Id your are free to use LoginId as foreign key:

```
public int LoginId {get; set;}
```

You'll see both methods used. Both have their advantages. The use of Id shows you immediately which property is the primary key. LoginId could also be used as foreign key. The name LoginId alone is not enough to see whether it is a primary key or a foreign key.

The defaults are usually plurals for collections of items where the item is the singular form. Here you'll see Login as class, and Logins as a set of objects of this class.

The article that helped me a lot to get on track using Entity Framework was [this entity framework tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx)

The tutorial tells you about how to use defaults, how to create one-to-many relations with foreign keys, many-to-many, various inheritance strategies, and what to do if you are not satisfied with a default model.